# How to build a website to upload and download file from blender by python?

Tags: python

I tried to ask this question in the most correct way for my knowledge on stackoverflow, but unfortunately as I believe I don't know an adequate language to ask a question like that I was canceled the question from the administrators (This is not a criticism, but it is only to introduce to the fact that I do not currently have the capacity to ask a question in technical language). So I try here, hoping the administrators understand and even suggest me how to correct my question.

I would like to build a script that will export / import certain files, directly from blender on a web platform that allows you to share files (.txt at this time), the files must have the possibility of being downloaded by other users, so I speak of a kind online library accessible by those who use my script.
Now my question is divided into 2 parts:

- What kind of web service can I use?
- What kind of python script/module can I use?

Basically I will accept answers that show me the way and to do a correct research.

If someone wants to correct the question to make it more technical, I think it's a good thing.

Comment: Are you trying to build that webservice yourself? Is Blender supposed to run on the client-side and interact with the webservice or is Blender supposed to run on the server-side? Please be aware that loading untrusted content from other users has security issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually there would be security problems, in fact I'm trying to figure out how to orient myself. Basically it's a question I asked for blender but it's more on the technical side of how to safely transfer files and where and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start with downloading**

It's a lot easier to get content from the web than it is to post to the net.  So we'll start there.

For more info than you can poke a stick at search google *et al* with

```
download files with python
```

Simple example uses python `requests` to download this question's page source into blenders text editor.  Any file that can be browsed  can be downloaded in this way.  For this can choose any web hosting.

```
import bpy
import requests


url = 'https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/how-to-build-a-website-to-upload-and-download-file-from-blender-by-python'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

t = bpy.data.texts.new("Question")
t.write(r.text)
bpy.context.space_data.text = t
```

Uploading is trickier, generally requires passwords etc, and is probably outside the scope of BSE.

Comment: Wow, ty batFinger  Does this also make it possible to download files hosted on a web site?

Comment: Yes. Alter `url` to test.